# asp.net razor: url param is not handed over

Tags: asp.net, razor

in my asp.net razor page i have a dynamically rendered button:

```
 <a href="@Url.Action("AddSubSub", "GlobalTagging", new { idOfSubsub = 3});">Add Subsub</a>
```

which fires this function:

```
public ActionResult AddSubSub(int? idOfSubsub)
{
    return RedirectToAction("Index", new { searchword = "" });
}
```

however, idOdSubsub is always returned as null, never as "3". Which i gave it in the `<a>`.

Why isnt the param handed over?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tested this and the problem is the semicolon at the end of your `href`, with the semicolon it produced an href of: `/GlobalTagging/AddSubSub?idOfSubsub=3;` (Doesn't work):

```
<a href="@Url.Action("AddSubSub", "GlobalTagging", new { idOfSubsub = 3});">Add Subsub</a>
```

If you remove the semicolon, it works and produces an href of: `/GlobalTagging/AddSubSub?idOfSubsub=3` (Works):

```
<a href="@Url.Action("AddSubSub", "GlobalTagging", new { idOfSubsub = 3})">Add Subsub</a>
```

Comment: 100% correct. thank you my friend! i was too blind... ;)